# TFS 2012 Build with VS 2013 IDE

Tags: tfsbuild

I have TFS 2012 with VS 2012 on build machine. Now Im trying to change the VS version on the build agent to VS 2013. It throws the errors like below. We have a bunch of customizations in the template and the template is looking for Vs/tfs 2012 assemblies only. Not sure where why this happens.

Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\" +

Comment: What is the build process template you're using? And if you just work with VS2012 not VS2013, will you get the same error? Please check my answer below for the details about how to build with VS2013 in TFS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to install VS2013 on the TFS build agent machine.

Secondly, modify the TFS build process template to target to use VS2013. Download the DefaultTemplate.11.1.xmal process template, find out the MSBuild activity and change the ToolPath to be "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin".

See this blog for the reference:

http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2013/10/building-visual-studio-2013-solutions.html